What is the longest cycle in the graph of academic papers and citations?
Okay, this is obviously just a fun and hopefully interesting question, but it is related to academia as a whole.
Sometimes two papers cite each other because they were published around the same time. However, citations should generally go in one direction, which is from older to newer. This is an easy consequence of causality. I am interested in examples of long cycles in the body of published and peer-reviewed papers.
EDIT: I should clarify that by a cycle of length n I mean a list of n papers where each one cites the next one and the last one cites the first one, and that "long" in the title refers to large n.

Does long refer to the numbers of papers in the cycle or the temporal distance (in publication date or similar)?

One of the issues in this question is how to define "paper". The looser a definition you use, the larger the cycles you will find.
